# Science fiction story about kids on another planet, seeing rain for the first time while one kid is locked in a closet

Tags: story-identification, space

It takes place on another planet (I think maybe Venus) about children seeing rain for the first time. They are waiting to see the rain and one boy locks another little kid in a closet or something like that who was originally from Earth, but left when they were young. They miss the rain, while the other kids enjoy it. I don't really remember the ending and wanted to try to find it again.

Comment: @Christi Unfortunately, we can't close it as such until the OP confirms that the answer below is correct.

Comment: Captain is King, have you considered accepting an answer to this question?

Answer (score 15):

This is a duplicate of an often asked question on this site.  Policy says it cannot be closed unless an answer is accepted here as well or the original poster comments that the ID is correct.  So, for what it's worth, this story is  Ray Bradbury's [*All Summer In a Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Summer_in_a_Day) (1954).

Wikipedia summary:

> The story is about a class of schoolchildren on Venus, which in this story is a world of constant rainstorms, where the Sun is only visible for one hour every seven years.
>
> One of the children, Margot, moved to Venus from Earth five years earlier, and she is the only one in her class to remember sunshine, since the Sun shone regularly on Earth. She describes the Sun as "a penny", or "like a fire in the stove", and the other children, being too young ever to have seen it themselves, do not believe her. She is bullied and ostracized by the other students and is locked in a closet down a tunnel.
>
> As the Sun is about to appear, their teacher arrives to take the class outside to enjoy their hour of sunshine and, in their astonishment and joy, they all forget about Margot. They run, play, skip, jump, and prance about, savoring every second of their newly found freedom. "It's much better than sun lamps!" one of them cries.
>
> Suddenly, a girl catches a raindrop in her hands. Thunder sounds, and they start to cry and run back inside. At this point one of them remembers Margot, who is still locked in the closet. Ashamed, they let her out of the closet, standing frozen, embarrassed over what they have done, and unable to "meet each other's glances."
>
> The precious Sun has come and gone and, because of their despicable act, Margot, who loved the Sun the most, has missed it.

Other similar questions:

- [Short story that takes place off planet, involving sun and rain](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/short-story-that-takes-place-off-planet-involving-sun-and-rain)
  (this is the "master" question that all others are closed as duplicates of)
- [World where it rains every day of the year except one?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24632/world-where-it-rains-every-day-of-the-year-except-one/24634) (accepted answer, closed as duplicate)
- [Short Story about Schoolchildren on Venus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39336/short-story-about-schoolchildren-on-venus/39337#39337) (acceptance via comment, closed as duplicate)
- [Story where a kid misses the window of sunlight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12233/story-where-a-kid-misses-the-window-of-sunlight/12236#12236) (accepted answer, closed as duplicate)
- [Story Identification: science fiction/fantasy, short story for high school English class](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74389/story-identification-science-fiction-fantasy-short-story-for-high-school-engli/74391#74391) (accepted answer, closed as duplicate)
- [Short story about human life on Venus; girl locked in cupboard during seven-yearly hour of sunlight](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119932/short-story-about-human-life-on-venus-girl-locked-in-cupboard-during-seven-year/119934#119934) (no accepted answer, no acceptance comment, but closed as duplicate anyway)

Comment: Actually, a comment saying that they’re the same is also enough.